# Mathematica - Using Manipulate[] with physical units

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, units-of-measurement

I'm a new user, and am trying to build a simple Boyle's law system in Mathematica. I want to include the units of the values, as I may need to perform some conversions later. If my quantities are a discrete list, they work fine. I cannot seem to get it to work for a slider.

I've searched for a while before posting this question. Here's my code:

```
    Manipulate[
     Text@Style[
       Grid[{
         {Row[{"Total fill volume is ", totalVolume}]},
         {Row[{"Delivery rate is ", deliveryRate}]},
         {Row[{"Product duration is ", 
            duration[totalVolume, deliveryRate]}]},
         {Row[{}]},
         {Row[{"Initial pressure is ", initialPressureG}]},
         {Row[{"Drop in pressure is ", pressureDrop, "%"}]}
         }, Alignment -> Left]
       ]
     ,
     {{totalVolume, Quantity[30, "ml"], "Total fill volume"}, 
      Quantity[{30, 45, 60, 90}, "ml"]},
     {{deliveryRate, Quantity[1, "ml/day"], "Delivery rate"}, 
      Quantity[{0.5, 1, 2, 3}, "ml/day"]},
     {initialPressureG, 0, 100},
     {{pressureDrop, 40, "Pressure drop"}, 0, 100, 5}
     ]
```

Instead of initialPressureG being a slider from 0 to 100, I want it to be a slider from 0psi to 100psi. Am I doing something stupidly wrong?

Comment: Head over to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com with your question, you're likely to get a better class of answer there.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to keep the slider values purely numeric make the transformation to a full quantity separately. Example:

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{valueWithQuantity = Quantity[value, "A"]},
  valueWithQuantity],
  {value, 0, 100}
]
```

This approach can be used in your code too

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pressureDrop = Quantity[pD, "psi"]},
  Text@Style[
    Grid[{{Row[{"Total fill volume is ", 
         totalVolume}]}, {Row[{"Delivery rate is ", 
         deliveryRate}]}, {Row[{"Product duration is ", 
         duration[totalVolume, 
          deliveryRate]}]}, {Row[{}]}, {Row[{"Initial pressure is ", 
         initialPressureG}]}, {Row[{"Drop in pressure is ", 
         pressureDrop, "%"}]}}, Alignment -> Left]]
  ], {{totalVolume, Quantity[30, "ml"], "Total fill volume"}, 
  Quantity[{30, 45, 60, 90}, "ml"]}, {{deliveryRate, 
   Quantity[1, "ml/day"], "Delivery rate"}, 
  Quantity[{0.5, 1, 2, 3}, "ml/day"]},
 {initialPressureG, 0, 100},
 {{pD, 40, "Pressure Drop"}, 0, 100, 5}
 ]
```

and you get what you expected.